# Fetching all apps from the notification bar android

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications, android-notification-bar, accessibilityservice

I have a requirement to fetch all the app notifications which already exists in the notification bar. For this purpose am using the `NotificationListenerService` along with the BroadcastReceiver to get the certain parameters like `Notification.EXTRA_TITLE`, `Notification.EXTRA_SUB_TEXT`, etc. But the problem am facing with `NotificationListenerService` is that I could not able to fetch the existing notification in the panel, wherein I could able to get the future notifications which i receives when the app is in foreground.
Kindly help me with this whether is there any property to get all the app notification which already presents in the notification bar. I am also posting the code that I am using for your reference.

**SimpleKitkatNotificationListener.java**

```
public class SimpleKitkatNotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

        Notification mNotification=sbn.getNotification();

        Log.i("notification",mNotification.tickerText.toString());
        if (mNotification!=null){
            Bundle extras = mNotification.extras;

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.INTENT_ACTION_NOTIFICATION);
            intent.putExtras(mNotification.extras);
            sendBroadcast(intent);

            Notification.Action[] mActions=mNotification.actions;
            if (mActions!=null){
                for (Notification.Action mAction:mActions){
                    int icon=mAction.icon;
                    CharSequence actionTitle=mAction.title;
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent=mAction.actionIntent;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

    }
}
```

And in Activity class am receiving the callbacks through `BroadcastReceiver` as follows

**MainActivity.java**

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
protected MyReceiver mReceiver = new MyReceiver();
public static String INTENT_ACTION_NOTIFICATION = "it.gmariotti.notification";

protected TextView title;
protected TextView text;
protected TextView subtext;
protected ImageView largeIcon;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Retrieve ui elements
    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nt_title);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nt_text);
    subtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nt_subtext);
    largeIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nt_largeicon);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_autorize:
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS");
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mReceiver == null) mReceiver = new MyReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(INTENT_ACTION_NOTIFICATION));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent != null) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            String notificationTitle = extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE);
            int notificationIcon = extras.getInt(Notification.EXTRA_SMALL_ICON);
            Bitmap notificationLargeIcon = ((Bitmap) extras.getParcelable(Notification.EXTRA_LARGE_ICON));
            Bitmap notificationSmallIcon = ((Bitmap) extras.getParcelable(Notification.EXTRA_SMALL_ICON));

            CharSequence notificationText = extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT);
            CharSequence notificationSubText = extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_SUB_TEXT);

            title.setText(notificationTitle);
            text.setText(notificationText);
            subtext.setText(notificationSubText);

            if (notificationLargeIcon != null) {
                largeIcon.setImageBitmap(notificationLargeIcon);
            }else if(notificationSmallIcon !=null){
                largeIcon.setImageBitmap(notificationSmallIcon);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

If anything above not clear kindly forgive me. Any piece of code and hind will be very helpful for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading the documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html

There is an example there of how you define a service to handle binding to an NLS. This will allow you to get an instance of NLS and use

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#getActiveNotifications()